# Сжатие string в C# и её decompress в mssql

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, gzip

В чём суть моей задачи: у меня есть список объектов, который неоходимо сериализовать в *json* и отправить его в другой сервис через вызов хранимой процедуры. Сериализуемые объекты, содержат свойство Body являющееся массивом *byte*. Значением этого свойства является сжатая строка. В другом сервисе она сохраняется в базу данных, если будет необходимость узнать изначальный текст, то должна быть возможность "разжать" её при чтении.

Проблема: выполняю сжатие начального текста с помощью *GZip*, сериализую объект в *json* вызываю хранимую процедуру, в базе данных всё сохраняется, но выполнить *DECOMPRESS* не получается. Выдаётся следующая ошибка: "SQL Error [9826] [S0001]: В качестве аргумента во встроенную инструкцию DECOMPRESS переданы несжатые или поврежденные данные."

Сравнил результат работы функции *COMPRESS* в *SQL* и *C#*, сжатые данные отличаются (определил по количеству байтов после сжатия).
Код, который использую для сжатия:

```
public static async Task<byte[]> CompressString(string source)
{
     byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(source);
            
     using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
          using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
          {
               await gzipStream.WriteAsync(bytes);
          }
          return memoryStream.ToArray();
     }
}
```

Менял *Unicode* на *UTF8*, *UTF32* и так далее.
Ещё вероятно проблема при сериализации. На сколько мне известно массив байт при сериализации в *C#* преобразуется в формат *Base64String*.

Код с помощью которого пытаются "разжать" строку на стороне *SQL*:

```
SELECT TOP 1 body_bin, CAST(DECOMPRESS(body_bin) AS nvarchar(max))
FROM dbo.Message m
ORDER BY m.key DESC
```

Я если честно не знаю, как в эту таблицу попадают данные, так как это не моя зона ответственности.

Для проверки работы, я выполнял сжатие с помощью приведённого выше кода, а также сериализовывать полученные байты в *Base64String*, как в коде ниже:

```
var base64CompressedBody = Convert.ToBase64String((await GZipCompressor.CompressString(message.Body)));
```

Дальше я копировал полученное значение из *base64CompressedBody* и пытался выполнить *DECOMPRESS*:

```
declare @val varchar(max), @value varbinary(max), @decompressed varchar(max);
set @val = 'H4sIAAAAAAAACh2MSw7CQAxDvfAJumI5B0DVaNrQz9BCERIsKnH/2/DaRWL5xU7j0S9nV3Ry0sUFt3hFR398VVJRp1ZZE7ugGZ/UkPsySQO7p1F9c9A92htfd24PyJPpyQRs8w86n+kKmWEriey7W74et/AbGpDwH3TJC92gAAAA'
set @value = cast(@val as varbinary(max));
set @decompressed = CAST(DECOMPRESS(@value) AS varchar(max));
select @value, @decompressed
```

Этот код не выполняется, выскакивает та же *SQL* ошибка:
"SQL Error [9826] [S0001]: В качестве аргумента во встроенную инструкцию DECOMPRESS переданы несжатые или поврежденные данные."

Кто-нибудь знает, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Возьми и обожми одну и ту же строку в C# и на SQL Server. И сравни результат побайтово.

Comment: Слишком много неизвестных. Какой именно сериализатор используется? _не знаю, как в эту таблицу попадают данные_ - ну и как угадать?

Comment: @Akina делал так, результаты разные. Не знаю как в SQL Server происходит сжатие и как сделать так, чтобы они работали одинаково

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov использую стандартный сериализатор JsonSerializer из System.Text.Json. То что я не знаю, как в таблицу попадают данные - это про то, какой путь они проходят после вызова хранимой процедуры, но вероятно просто INSERT. Я там написал, что обхожу этот момент самостоятельным вызовом DECOMPRESS со скопированным сжатым значением (см. последний листинг)

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо большое, что потом с этим можно будет сделать? :) Я не так силён в архивации ((

Comment: Ваша задача приобретает сделующий ответ  данные =  шапка+  memoryStream.ToArray() + контрольнаясумма + размер.

Comment: @nick_n_a первые 16 байт - шапка, последние 8 байт - размер, предпоследние 8 байт - кс, а остальное сами сжатые значения? То есть мне надо сравнивать значения между 9 байтом и length-16?

Comment: Я зря ударился в расшифровку потока, ф-ция COMPRESS даёт тот же самый результат что и GZipStream. У вас только проблема с согласованием данных.

Comment: @nick_n_a а как можно поменять код на си шарпе, чтобы найти тот алгоритм, который использует sql? он действительно даёт другой результат. Какие ещё есть методы компрессии?

Comment: Вы где-то запутались. Всё должно работать. На каком именно этапе ошибка?

Comment: Последний кусок кода - так нельзя делать. Если вы завернули в base64 - то надо развернуть назад в байты, а только потом декомпрессию делать. Первый кусок кода написан правильно. Я проверил CompressString - он отрабатывает верно.

Comment: Зачем вам base64? Используйте blob и выставьте тим varbinary. Тогда вам неприйдётся перепаковывать base64 в байты, и вы не будете терять размер.

Comment: вот распаковка base64 но её надо допилить https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191273/decode-base64-string-natively-in-sql-server

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` - используйте `Encoding.UTF8`. Нет никакого смысла здесь использовать UTF-16. Весить готовая строка будет тоже меньше.

Comment: Нет, UTF8 нельзя в данном случае. Если UTF8 - то нужно будет mssql обьяснить что данные в utf8, а это проблематично. varchar это ANSI а Unicode это nvarchar. А UTF8 - прийдётся скрипя зубами конвертить. Автор и так base64 упустил конвертацию.

Comment: @nick_n_a огромное вам спасибо !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По итогу...

1. Ф-ция CompressString отрабатывает хорошо, даёт результат идеинтичный COMPRESS
2. base64encode запаковано правильно.
3. Вы пытаетесь base64 сделать decompress, это нельзя делать. Как складывали "матрёшку" так и разбираем - сначало base64decode а только потом decompress.

Решаю вашу задачу. Находим код "decode base64 mssql"

Берем код тут https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191273/decode-base64-string-natively-in-sql-server

И немного вправим мозги ему

Алгоримт - берем ваш base64 распаковываем-преобразуем в байты. Потом делаем decompress этим байтам, то что получилось - кастим в строку.

```
SELECT 
cast(
 DECOMPRESS(
    CONVERT
    (
        VARBINARY(MAX), 
        CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("BASE64_COLUMN"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)')
    ) )  as nvarchar(max))AS RESULT
FROM
    (
          --- ваш @val
        SELECT 'H4sIAAAAAAAACh2MSw7CQAxDvfAJumI5B0DVaNrQz9BCERIsKnH/2/DaRWL5xU7j0S9nV3Ry0sUFt3hFR398VVJRp1ZZE7ugGZ/UkPsySQO7p1F9c9A92htfd24PyJPpyQRs8w86n+kKmWEriey7W74et/AbGpDwH3TJC92gAAAA' AS BASE64_COLUMN
    ) A
```

Но я бы так не делал, base64 расходует много места.

Я бы передал blob в параметрах и просто сделал `SELECT cast( DECOMPRESS(@param1) as nvarchar(max))` возможно это не всегда возможно - тогда делайте как выше.

P.S.

`select Compress('AAA')` - запакует 3 байта в формате ANSI т.е. varchar. Применив collate можно выкрутиться с кодировкой. Utf8 - неподскажу, прямо конвертить умеет с mssql 2019, можно конвертировать обходным путём но это 3-х этажные выражения будут.

`select Compress(N'AAA')`  - запакует 6 байт в формате UNICODE т.е. nvarchar.

Соответственно тут ANSI/UNICODE - это один из шагов где можно запутаться. Скорее всего несовпадение байт было связано с тем, что перепутали кодировку. Плюс кодировка base64 вносит немного путаницы.

Comment: это работает !!! спасибо вам большое!